# Flutter : unhandled exception: invalid argument

Tags: api, flutter, dart, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to send two list of images file and i have an error with that and i don't know why this happen
this is the function which i use for that :

```
Future<dynamic> upload(List<File> imageFile, List<File> backID) async {

    var headers =
        Provider.of<LoginUserProvider>(context, listen: false).httpHeader;
    var uri = Uri.parse(
        "xyz");

    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    var requestCopy = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    //request.headers.addAll(Environment.requestHeaderMedia);
    for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFilesList.length; i++) {
      var length = await imageFile[i].length();
      var stream =
          // ignore: deprecated_member_use
          new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile[i].openRead()));
      var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile(
        'back_id_photos[$i]',
        stream,
        length,
        contentType: MediaType('application', 'x-tar'),
      );
      var multipartFilePhotos = new http.MultipartFile(
        'photos[$i]',
        stream,
        length,
        contentType: MediaType('application', 'x-tar'),
      );
      request.fields['section_id'] = VillaID.toString();
      request.fields['start_date'] = requeststartDate;
      request.fields['end_date'] = requestendDate;
      request.fields['names'] = _nameController.toString();
      request.fields['phones'] = _phoneController.toString();
      request.fields['photos'] = multipartFilePhotos.toString();
      request.fields['back_id_photos'] = multipartFile.toString();
      //contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png'));

      request.files.add(multipartFile);
      request.files.add(multipartFilePhotos);
      var response = await request.send();
      print(response.statusCode);
      response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
        print(value);
      });
      var streamedResponse = await requestCopy.send();
      var responses = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
      // ignore: unused_local_variable
      final responseData = json.decode(responses.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print(json.decode(responses.body));
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

and in the part of

```
var response = await request.send();
```

I have the error exactly before the dot (.) and this is the error which shown

> unhandled exception: invalid argument(s) (input): must not be null
> Can anyone tell me what should i do to solve that !

Comment: some argument value passed is null, check related methods, with arguments and make sure they not have a null value

Comment: I would suggest apply debug point on each data you are adding to request and check what are you sending for request.send().

Comment: how can i check if some data is null

Answer (score 2):

Send your Multipart Part Files as below and **Use** `await http.Multipart` as **accessing file is async function** and need a promise to run.

Try this:

```
await http.MultipartFile(
    'back_id_photos[$i]',
    stream,
    length,
    contentType: MediaType('application', 'x-tar'),
  );
```

OR

```
request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', await File.fromUri("<path/to/file>").readAsBytes(), contentType: new MediaType('image', 'jpeg')))
```

[Follow this link](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html)